# Angular2 Submodule Import Issue

Tags: angular

I have an issue with a submodule using NgSemanticModule. The module itself works without the NgSemantic tags inside the submodule components template. Trying to use the NgSemantig Components fails inside my submodule. If I use the HeaderComponent template in my AppComponent template the same code works. How to import the NgSemantic Module at the Header Module Level?

Header Module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HeaderComponent } from "./header.component";
import { NgSemanticModule } from "ng-semantic";


@NgModule({
   declarations: [
   HeaderComponent
],
imports: [
 NgSemanticModule
],
providers: [],
exports:[
  HeaderComponent
 ]
})

export class HeaderModule { }
```

Header Component:

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
 @Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent{}
```

Header Template:

```
<sm-menu title="Angular2" class="inverted teal" logo="/assets/images/semantic.png">
<a sm-item *ngFor="let item of items" [icon]="item.icon">{{item?.title}}</a>

<sm-menu class="menu right secondary">
<a sm-item href="#/elements/menu"
   image="http://semantic-ui.com/images/avatar/small/stevie.jpg">Elliot Fu</a>
<a sm-item icon="sidebar big"></a>
```

My App Module:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NgSemanticModule } from "ng-semantic";
import { HeaderModule } from "./header/";

@NgModule({
 declarations: [
   AppComponent
 ],
 imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    NgSemanticModule,
    HeaderModule
  ],
  providers: [],
   bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

App Component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 template: '<app-header></app-header>',
 styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'] 
 })
 export class AppComponent {}
```

Exception:

```
unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. ("<sm-menu     title="Angular2" class="inverted teal" logo="/assets/images/semantic.png">
<a sm-item [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let item of items" [icon]="item.icon">   {{item?.title}}</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should import the `CommonModule` inside your `HeaderModule`. This module contains the common directives from `angular2` (like `*ngFor`).

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { HeaderComponent } from "./header.component";
import { NgSemanticModule } from "ng-semantic";


@NgModule({
   declarations: [
      HeaderComponent
   ],
   imports: [
      NgSemanticModule,
      CommonModule
   ],
   providers: [

   ],
   exports:[
       HeaderComponent
   ]
})

export class HeaderModule {}
```

Comment: I haven't imported the CommonModule in my App.Module, but the App.Component works though. Why do I have to import it in my HeaderModule?

Comment: The CommonModule is included in the BrowserModule which you do import in the AppComponent. But you are only allowed to import the BrowserModule once :) (in your root module)

Comment: Yes, I tried to import it before but it didn't work. A2 is really frustrating.

Comment: It's all explained in the great documentation at [angular.io](https://angular.io)